# How does kubernetes volume mounts map to docker volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and experimenting with volumes. I have a docker image which declares 2 volumes as in :

```
VOLUME ["/db/mongo/data" , "/db/mongo/log"]
```

I am using a StatefulSet , wherein I have 2 volume mounts, as in --

```
volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-vol
              mountPath: << path1 >>
              subPath: data
            - name: mongo-vol
              mountPath: << path2 >>
              subPath: log
```

My question is i) should path1 & path2 be mentioned as "/db/mongo/data" and "/db/mongo/log" respectively ??

ii) Or it can be any path where the volumes would be mounted inside the container, and "/db/mongo/data" & "/db/mongo/log" container paths would be automatically mapped to those mount points ?

I tried reading up the documentation and tried both options but some confusion still remains. Appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both volume mounts reference to the same volume `mongo-vol`. That tells me this is a volume containing the `data` and `log` directories. You should use `/db/mongo/log` and `/db/mongo/data` as your `mountPath`s, and specify the `subPath` as `log` and `data` respectively. That will mount the volume referenced by `mongo-vol`, and mount `data` and `log` directories in that volume on to those directories.

If you had two seperate volumes, a `mongo-data` and `mongo-log`, then you would mount them the same way, without the `subPath`, because you are not referencing sub-directories under the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So that indicates to me that the mountPath should exactly  correspond to the docker volume published. Tried it out and now I have much more clarity.